# Access form does not display new record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access form bound to a table that includes a foreign key. The form has a frame control with an After_Update event that activates an ADODB command to insert a new record to the table with the same foreign key value (lngSlctdEntrantID) along with adding values to a couple of other fields. (the only required field in the table is the Primary Key, which is an AutoIncrement field). The code continues by setting a filter to show all records associated to the foreign key value (which should only be 2 records - the record for the existing assignment (which the form displays correctly) and a new record for the new assignment). The code performs exactly as it should but the new record is not displayed on the form. I have tried the following:

1. Resetting the filter after the command is executed
2. Requery the form (also tried Refresh and Repaint, though I think Requery is the correct choice)
3. Check state on the ADODB command
4. Check if new record exists with ADODB recordset limited to the new ID value.

The code used in the frame control is as follows:

```
Private Sub fraCoachOrMentor_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo Err_fCOM_AU

    Dim intCoachMentor As Integer
    Dim strSlctdStaff As String
    Dim strEntrantName As String
    Dim lngSlctdEntrantID As Long
    Dim lngLifeCoachAssigneeID As Long
    Dim cnnMain As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sqlChk As String
    Dim sqlChkNewTrsfr As String
    Dim rstChk As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dteAssign As Date
    Dim sqlAdd As String
    Dim sqlUpdate As String
    Dim cmdAddUpdate As ADODB.Command
    Dim lngNewAssignedID As Long
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim strAddForm As String
    Dim strThisForm As String
    Dim intChk As Integer

    intChk = 0

    intCoachMentor = fraCoachOrMentor

    cboLifeCoach.Visible = False
    txtLifeCoachName.Visible = False
    cboMentor.Visible = False
    txtMentorName.Visible = False
    Me.Section(0).Visible = False
    intChk = 1
    
    lblHlpAction.Visible = True
    
    If intCoachMentor = 1 Then
        cboLifeCoach.Visible = True
        txtLifeCoachName.Visible = True
        lblCrntCoachMentor.Caption = "Life Coach"
        lblTrnsfrReason.Caption = "Life Coach Transfer Reason"
        lblHlpAction.Caption = "Select a new Life Coach for this Resident and enter a reason for the transfer"
    ElseIf intCoachMentor = 2 Then
        cboMentor.Visible = True
        txtMentorName.Visible = True
        lblCrntCoachMentor.Caption = "Mentor"
        lblTrnsfrReason.Caption = "Mentor Transfer Reason"
        lblHlpAction.Caption = "Select a new Mentor for this Resident and enter a reason for the transfer"
    End If
    intChk = 2

    lngSlctdEntrantID = cboSlctResident
    dteAssign = CDate(Int(Now()))
    Me.Section(0).Visible = True
    intChk = 3
    
    strFilter = "[EntrantID] = " & lngSlctdEntrantID & " And (IsNull([AssignStop]) Or [AssignStop] >= #" & dteAssign & "#)"

    Me.Filter = strFilter
    Me.FilterOn = True
    intChk = 4
    
    If intCoachMentor = 1 Then
        sqlChkNewTrsfr = "SELECT LifeCoachAssigneeID, EntrantID, AssignStart, MntrPersonID, LCPersonID " _
            & "FROM LifeCoachAssignees WHERE (((EntrantID)=" & lngSlctdEntrantID & ") AND " _
            & "(((AssignStart)>=#" & dteAssign & "#) AND ((LCPersonID)>0)));"
        sqlChk = "SELECT LifeCoachAssigneeID, EntrantID, AssignStart, MntrPersonID, LCPersonID " _
            & "FROM LifeCoachAssignees WHERE (((EntrantID)=" & lngSlctdEntrantID & ") AND ((LCPersonID)>0));"
            strSlctdStaff = "Life Coach"
    ElseIf intCoachMentor = 2 Then
        sqlChkNewTrsfr = "SELECT LifeCoachAssigneeID, EntrantID, AssignStart, MntrPersonID, LCPersonID " _
            & "FROM LifeCoachAssignees WHERE (((EntrantID)=" & lngSlctdEntrantID & ") AND " _
            & "(((AssignStart)>=#" & dteAssign & "#) AND ((MntrPersonID)>0)));"
        sqlChk = "SELECT LifeCoachAssigneeID, EntrantID, AssignStart, MntrPersonID, LCPersonID " _
            & "FROM LifeCoachAssignees WHERE (((EntrantID)=" & lngSlctdEntrantID & ") AND ((MntrPersonID)>0));"
            strSlctdStaff = "Mentor"
    End If
    intChk = 5

    Set cnnMain = New ADODB.Connection
    cnnMain.ConnectionString = cnstCnctMain
    cnnMain.Open
    intChk = 6

    Set rstChk = New ADODB.Recordset
    rstChk.Open sqlChkNewTrsfr, cnnMain, adOpenKeyset
    If rstChk.RecordCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "A new transfer effective today has already been added for " & strSlctdStaff & " for " & strEntrantName & "." & Chr(13) _
        & "Both the new assignment as well as the previous (if there was a previous assignment for " & strSlctdStaff & ") is now displayed.", vbOKOnly, "Today's New Transfer"
        rstChk.Close
        GoTo DisplayNewTransfer
    Else
        rstChk.Close
    End If
    intChk = 7

    Set rstChk = New ADODB.Recordset
    rstChk.Open sqlChk, cnnMain, adOpenKeyset
    If rstChk.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This Resident, " & strEntrantName & ", has not been assigned a " & strSlctdStaff & " yet." & Chr(13) _
        & "The system will now open the screen for adding a new assignment for " & strEntrantName & ".", vbOKOnly, "Resident Without Assignment"
        rstChk.Close
        strAddForm = "frmHouseAssign"
        strThisForm = Me.Name
        Application.Echo False
        If strAddForm <> "" And CurrentProject.AllForms(strAddForm).IsLoaded = False Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm strAddForm
        End If
        DoCmd.Close acForm, strThisForm
        Application.Echo True
        GoTo Exit_fCOM_AU
    Else
        rstChk.Close
    End If
    intChk = 8

    lngLifeCoachAssigneeID = [LifeCoachAssigneeID]
    txtOriginalRcrd = lngLifeCoachAssigneeID
    strEntrantName = cboSlctResident.Column(1)
    intChk = 9

    sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO LifeCoachAssignees ( EntrantID, AssignStart, StartWasTransfer, IsCurrent, Added, AddedByID ) " _
        & "SELECT " & lngSlctdEntrantID & " AS EntrantID, #" & Now() & "# AS AssignStart, -1 AS StartWasTransfer, " _
        & "-1 AS IsCurrent, #" & Now() & "# AS Added, " & lngLogeeID & " AS AddedByID;"

    Set cmdAddUpdate = New ADODB.Command
    cmdAddUpdate.CommandText = sqlAdd
    cmdAddUpdate.ActiveConnection = cnnMain
    cmdAddUpdate.Execute
    Set cmdAddUpdate = Nothing
    intChk = 10
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    lngNewAssignedID = DMax("LifeCoachAssigneeID", "LifeCoachAssignees")

    sqlUpdate = "UPDATE LifeCoachAssignees SET AssignStop = #" & dteAssign & "#, StopWasTransfer = -1 " _
        & "WHERE (((LifeCoachAssigneeID)=" & lngLifeCoachAssigneeID & "));"

    Set cmdAddUpdate = New ADODB.Command
    cmdAddUpdate.CommandText = sqlUpdate
    cmdAddUpdate.ActiveConnection = cnnMain
    cmdAddUpdate.Execute
    Set cmdAddUpdate = Nothing
    intChk = 11
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

    sqlChk = "SELECT EntrantID FROM LifeCoachAssignees WHERE (((LifeCoachAssigneeID) = " & lngNewAssignedID & "));"
    Set rstChk = New ADODB.Recordset
    rstChk.Open sqlChk, cnnMain, adOpenKeyset

ChkAgain:
    If rstChk.RecordCount = 0 Then
        GoTo ChkAgain
    End If
    rstChk.Close

    Me.Requery

DisplayNewTransfer:

    Application.Echo False
    Me.Filter = ""
    Me.FilterOn = False
    intChk = 12

    strFilter = "[EntrantID] = " & lngSlctdEntrantID & " And (IsNull([AssignStop]) Or [AssignStop] >= #" & dteAssign & "#)"

    Me.Filter = strFilter
    Me.FilterOn = True

    Application.Echo True
    intChk = 13



Exit_fCOM_AU:
    cnnMain.Close
    Set cnnMain = Nothing
    Exit Sub
    
    
Err_fCOM_AU:
    MsgBox "Error coming from Coach or Mentor After Update at " & intChk & ". Err # " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_fCOM_AU

End Sub
```

Comment: Why code to create record and not bound form/subform for data entry?

Comment: Is form DataEntry property set to Yes? Have you step debugged? Are variables populated with correct data?

Comment: The new record shows up promptly when the "Refresh All" option is clicked on the ribbon, so I know the record has been added. The ribbon will not be visible to the user of the app.

Comment: It is a bound form. The reason for the particular arrangement is for the user to see the previous assignment at the same time as the record for the new assignment. As a result only the 2 records for the selected EntrantID are visible.

Comment: All variables that are being populated do have the correct data. I have debugged. After the code to insert the record is run I have a code line that finds the ID value for the new record. Since it is the autoincrement field it will be the max value in the table. This code is immediately after the insert command execute line. It does not find the correct value at that point in the code, so I know the problem is that the table has not been updated before the rest of the code runs. I have added a button to the form to set the view and that works correctly but I did not want to rely on that.

Comment: If ribbon Refresh works then VBA Requery should work. Perhaps you should post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis. I have never had issue with VBA creating record and that record being available for subsequent code. Access should not be processing code until it is finished committing record.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the *RecordsetClone* of the form for the update - something like this:

```vb
Dim Records As DAO.Recordset

Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone

lngNewAssignedID = DMax("LifeCoachAssigneeID", "LifeCoachAssignees")

' Add new record.
Records.AddNew
    Records!EntrantID.Value = lngSlctdEntrantID
    Records!AssignStart.Value = Now
    Records!StartWasTransfer.Value = True
    Records!IsCurrent.Value = True
    Records!Added.Value = Now
    Records!AddedByID.Value = lngLogeeID
Records.Update 

' Update current record.
Records.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
Records.Edit
    Records!AssignStop.Value = dteAssign
    Records!StopWasTransfer.Value = True
Records.Update

Records.Close
```

That will update the form automatically and instantly.

Comment: June7 thanks for your advice. I appreciate your confirmation that the continuing code should not complete until the record has been committed. Gustav thanks for the nice explanation of using DAO vs ADO. I would do that but the current backend is Access but is being prepared to go to SQL Server and DAO would not be appropriate for a SQL Server table. Thanks though, nice easy solution.

Comment: DAO works with _any_ linked table, and `RecordsetClone` exists for any _bound_ form.